# Is there a difference between starting a program from the terminal vs the launcher?

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal

So, the title says it all. Is there some fundamental difference between starting a program from the terminal compared to the launcher?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference. Launcher icons are `.desktop` files which are somewhat similar to Windows shortcuts. Those files have exec line which calls the actual binary file for that program , possibly with specific options

Launching Firefox from terminal , for example, calls the actual Firefox binary.

Terminal commands also are attached to the shell of that terminal which called them. Unless you append & at the end of a command or `nohup`, the terminal will wait for that app to finish, and wont respond to any other command ( but will respond to keyboard interupt , or signals such as SIGKILL or SIGSTOP)